# GPO to configure Excel 2013?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-excel

Using Excel 2013 (Office 2013, 32-bit, per MS recommendation) on Windows 7 Professional, 64bit in a Server 2008R2 domain.

When trying to open an Excel 2013 document, we're getting the error box: `There was a problem sending the command to the program`.

The Microsoft solution to this is to uncheck `Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)` in Excel.

How can I do this in AD and push it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'll need the Office 2013 Administrative Template files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554), and the setting is at:

`Administrative Templates\Excel 2013\Excel Options\Advanced\`
Named: `Ignore Other Applications`

Alternately, the registry key controlling this behavior is:

`HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Options\BinaryOptions\`
Named: `fDDEEnabled_6_1`, `REG_DWORD` type, and takes a `1` or a `0`.  At least in Office 2007 and 2010, `1` was off and `0` was on, so it's probably the same for Office 2013.

Comment: Got the downloads.  THank you.  Should these be extracted into the domain server's c:\windows\sysvol\domain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions folder?

Comment: @user52874 That's one location for them, the other is on the local machine at `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-us`.  (Obviously, assuming US, English).